# How to import a font into Xcode 4 interface builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, interface-builder

I have a custom font in an (iOS) Xcode 4 project. This works fine, but whilst coding, I would like to visualise this same font in the textviews/labels in Interface Builder instead of showing an approximately equivalent font.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible at this time for custom fonts to show up in IB.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible brother for IB yet :)